# Type Error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from my local storage in my app.js component and passing it to other components using context api hook. Using that data I am displaying my Cart but when I reload my cart page my cart get empty .I have used Object.keys() method to convert my object keys into array.

my App.js Code

```
import {React ,useState ,useEffect} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router ,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Products from './components/Products';
import Cart from './components/Cart';
import SingleItem from './components/SingleItem';
import {CartContext} from './components/CartContext';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import {PaymentForm} from './components/PaymentForm'
function App() {
  const [cart,setCart]=useState({});
 
  useEffect(() => {
    
      const cart=window.localStorage.getItem('cart');
      setNav(false);
      console.log(showNav);
      console.log(JSON.parse(cart));
  }, [])
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart))
  }, [cart]);

  return (
   <>
   <Router>
     <CartContext.Provider value={{cart,setCart}}>
  
     <Nav/>
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/" component={Home} exact></Route>
       <Route path="/products" exact component={Products}></Route>
       <Route path="/products/:id" component={SingleItem}></Route>
       <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} exact></Route>
       <Route path="/PaymentForm" component={PaymentForm} exact></Route>
     </Switch>
      
     </CartContext.Provider>
    
   </Router>
   </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

My cart.js code

```
import  {useContext, useEffect ,useState} from 'react'
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import {CartContext} from './CartContext';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import contents from './contents';
import './styles.css';
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm'
function Cart() {
    const [products,setproducts]= useState([]);
    let total=0;
    const {cart,setCart}= useContext(CartContext)
    console.log(cart.totalItems);
    console.log(cart);
       useEffect(() => {
           if(cart.totalItems===0)
           {
            console.log("empty");
            return (<img className="mx-auto w-3/4 mt-12" src="/images/emptycart.jpg" alt="" />)
        
           }
           else
           {
               console.log(Object.keys(cart.items));

           
            (Object.keys(cart.items)).map((m,i)=>{
                
                contents.map((content,j)=>{
                    if(content._id===m )
                {
                    console.log("naman",i,j);  
                   if(products){
                     products.push(content);
                   }
                    console.log(content.name);
                }
    
                })
                
            })
        } 
       }, [cart]);
       

       console.log(contents);
         
       const getquantity=(product)=>{
           return(cart.items[product._id])
       }
       
      const increment=(product)=>{
          const oldqty=cart.items[product._id];
          const _cart={...cart};
          _cart.items[product._id]=oldqty+1;
          _cart.totalItems++;
          setCart(_cart);

      }
      const decrement=(product)=>{
          const oldqty=cart.items[product._id];
          const _cart={...cart};
         
          if(oldqty===1)
          {
              return
          }
          _cart.items[product._id]=oldqty-1;
          _cart.totalItems--;
          setCart(_cart);


      }
      const getSum=(product)=>{
           const p=product.price
           const sum=p*getquantity(product)
           let t=0
           sum?total=total+sum:t=1;
          return sum;    
      }
      const Ondelete=(productid)=>{
        const _cart={...cart};
        const oldqty=_cart.items[productid];
         delete( _cart.items[productid]);
         console.log(cart.items);
      
         _cart.totalItems=_cart.totalItems-oldqty;
        alert("Item deleted from Cart")
         setCart(_cart);
      }
      const orderNow=()=>{
        < paymentForm/>
          
      }
      
      
  
    return (
        cart.totalItems? 
        <div>
            <div className="container mb-10 pr-20 ">
                <h1 className="font-bold my-5  mx-40 font">Cart Items</h1>
                <ul>
                    {
                                    contents.map((content,i)=>{
                                        var product=content;
                    
                                     if(cart.items[product._id])
                                     {
                                        return(<li className="mb-12" key={i}>
                                            
                                        <div className="maincart ">
                                        <div className=" maincontent ">
                                            <img className="maincartimg ml-5 "src={content.img} alt="" />
                                            <span className="ml-5 font-bold font ">{content.name}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="cartcontainer">
                                            <button onClick={()=>decrement(product)} className="bg-yellow-500 py-2 px-4 rounded-full addbtn leading-none">-</button>
                                            <span className="font-bold px-4">{getquantity(product)?getquantity(product):0}</span>
                                            <button onClick={()=>increment(product)} className="bg-yellow-500 py-2 px-4 rounded-full addbtn leading-none">+</button>
                                        </div>
                                      <div className="cartbtn">
                                      <span className="font m-10">{getquantity(product)?getSum(product):0}</span>
                                        <button onClick={()=>Ondelete(product._id)} className="bg-red-500 px-4 py-2 rounded-full addbtn leading-none"><i class="fas fa-trash mr-2"></i>Delete</button>
                                      </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        {}
                                    </li>)}
                                    

                                    
                                    })}
    
                                

                </ul>
                <hr className="my-6"/>
              <div className="order">
              <div className="text-right pr-20"> <span className="font-bold"> <b>TOTAL PRICE:</b>{total}</span></div>
                <div className="text-right mt-6 pr-20 " ><Link to="/PaymentForm" className="bg-yellow-500 px-4 py-2 rounded-full">Order Now</Link></div>

              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        :
      <div className="emptycart">
          <h1 className=" mt-3 text-4xl font-bold"> Empty Cart</h1>
           <img className="mx-auto mb-5 emptycartimg w-1/2 mt-5" src="/images/emptycart.jpg" alt="" />
           </div>
        
       
     
    )
    
}


export default Cart
```

Error on reloading cart page

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/react cart/my-cart/src/components/Cart.js:23
  20 |           }
  21 |           else
  22 |           {
> 23 |               console.log(Object.keys(cart.items));
     | ^  24 | 
  25 |           
  26 |            (Object.keys(cart.items)).map((m,i)=>{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you can't create an array of keys from an undefined object.

```
Object.keys(cart.items))
```

```js
const cart = {};

Object.keys(cart.items);
```

You should provide valid initial `cart` state in the provider that includes an `items` property.

```
function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState({ items: {} });
 
  ...

  return (
    <Router>
      <CartContext.Provider value={{ cart, setCart }}>
        ...
```

```js
const cart = { items: {} };

console.log(Object.keys(cart.items));
```

#### Update

The reason the `cart` state persistence isn't working is because you don't initialize your state from localStorage. The second `useEffect` is wiping any persisted cart data out.

```
function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState({}); // <-- (1) initially empty
 
  useEffect(() => {
      const cart = window.localStorage.getItem('cart');
      setNav(false);
      console.log(showNav);
      console.log(JSON.parse(cart));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem( // <-- (2) writes initial empty state
      'cart',
      JSON.stringify(cart),
    );
  }, [cart]);
```

You should initialize your local `cart` state from localStorage, and in the case that localStorage is empty, return the valid initial state.

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState(() => {
  return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("cart")) || { items: {} }
});
```

Comment: Still not working. I think my error is because when I reload my page It takes time to get data from local storage and my component gets loaded due to which cart remains empty and it display error please tell me some way to solve this

Comment: and my cart is not empty I am adding items into cart through a product page. Problem is that my cart contains item but when I reload cart page my cart get empty

Comment: @NamanGarg That would be a separate issue to the one you asked about with the error. If I had to guess, you need to initialize your `cart` state from local storage in the first `useEffect` hook, or do it in an initializer function for the `useState` hook. The second `useEffect` is the one clearing the localStorage with the initial `cart` state missing the `items` property.

Comment: Thank you very much my code is working well now.You have helped me a lot